# set var from click by jQuery, send to nested chain with Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x popovers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the href atribute from click and send it to a nested function.
But it doesn't work.

```
$('.pop').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var img = $(this).attr('href');
}).popover({
    content: '<img src="' + img + '" />',
    html: true,
    placement: top
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that, `popover()` is instantiated on page load, changing the variable later on click wont have any effect, and the variable is out of scope as well.

Comment: Are you getting an error of any kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of your img var. Make it global (define outside your onclick). After this it is undefined still in the scope of popover, so set your content by a function.

```
var img;    
$('.pop').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     img = $(this).attr('href');         
}).popover({
    content: function(){return '<img src="' + img + '" />';},
    html: true,
    placement: top
});
```

see: http://bootply.com/66575